# How to build Cross Compiler Toolchain on Fedora for other Linux distributions?

Tags: gcc, g++, cross-compiling, fedora, toolchain

my Linux: Fedora 14 x64
my gcc: 4.5.1
my Glibc： 2.12.90

target Linux: "Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS" hardy
target kernel: 2.6.24-29-server x64
target gcc: 4.2.4
target Glibc： 2.7

I need gcc/g++ and fortran.

I Googled and most documents I found are somehow outdated and targeting for ARM, not for other Linux.

Any step by step document will be greatly appreciated.

THanKs.

Answer (score 0):

Building cross-compilers is [quite complicated](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/492).

Assuming you just want to build an application that will run on "Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS", you don't really have to build the cross-compiler first.

[Apgcc](http://www.autopackage.org/apbuild-apgcc.php) provides a much simpler path, and the resulting application will run just about everywhere.

Update:
autopackage.org was alive back in 2011, but has gone away ;-(  This [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110725024317/http://autopackage.org/) says it merged with [Linstaller](http://linstaller.sourceforge.net/), which at the moment appears to have no content.

Comment: You linked to autopackage.org which appears to be dead at the moment